# Pixels contain different values than what is exported?

Tags: c#, .net, imagemagick

I am using Magick.NET to read and write exr files and transfer data to an external encoder.
I noticed that the exr files Imagemagick writes contain the correct values.

When I try to read the pixels myself, they are extraordinarily large.

While the exr file has values between 0.0 and 1.0, the pixel value in the program is withint the 1000.0 and higher.
[image: a.exr inspector]
[image: grafik]

I want the values that are within the exr file since these were the values I process within my program

Comment: My guess is that the viewer is scaling the stored color values to make them fit into 0 .. 1 range for display. Try to store a picture with white and black pixels in the exact same format and you will see what the internal range is.

Comment: According to https://imagemagick.org/script/high-dynamic-range.php, 
ImageMagick writes "in quantum depth", which in my case is 16 bit HDRI. Dividing the pixel values by `65535.0f` seems to result in what I want.

Comment: You can insert your comment as an answer and tick the checkmark to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://imagemagick.org/script/high-dynamic-range.php), ImageMagick writes "in quantum depth", which in my case is 16 bit HDRI. Dividing the pixel values by `65535.0f` seems to result in what I want.